# Looping Object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How can I build a loop in JavaScript?

```
var input = {0:['S','M','L','XL'],1:['Red','Blue','Black']};
var output =
{ 
 0:['S','Red'],
 1:['S','Blue'],    
 2:['S','Black'],
 3:['M','Red'],
 4:['M','Blue'],
 5:['M','Black'],
 6:['L','Red'],
 7:['L','Blue'],
 8:['L','Black'],
 9:['XL','Red'],
 10:['XL','Blue'],
 11:['XL','Black'],   
};
```

I will render Html from output

Comment: What have you got? Do you know javascript?

Comment: That isn't valid JavaScript, so we can't help you loop through it.

Comment: Every basic question about looping through things in JavaScript, whether [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) or [objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object), **has been asked and answered already** on SO. Search before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write this function for him. Please don't justify people from how he write the code. Maybe it's easy to say "Hey! Do you know javascript?".

It's better if you leave some answer or stay quite. His code is valid javascript.

https://gist.github.com/ethaizone/b7d3a833dcdeb80234dde516649ac06d#file-buildmultidimentionarray2-js